# How can I send an image from an input type="file" to my SQL database with React and Node?

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I would like to get an image from an input of type="file" and send it to my SQL database but I don't know how to do this ?

Here is my Node.js function :

```
app.post("/ajouter-mon-restaurant", (req, res) => {

  const name = req.body.name;
  const address = req.body.address;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const formData = req.body.formData;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO restaurant (nom, adresse, description, image_resto) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
    [name, address, description, formData],
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
});
```

And here is my React code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

import './ajouterMonRestaurant.css';

function AjouterMonRestaurant() {

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  
    const addMyRestaurantToDatabase = () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('myFile', image, image.name);
        // console.log(formData);
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/ajouter-mon-restaurant", {
        name: name,
        address: address,
        description: description,
        formData: formData,
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      });
    };

    const fileChangedHandler = (event) => {
        setImage(event.target.files[0]);
    };


    return(
        <div>
                <div className='mainContainerAjouterMonResto'>                  
                   <div class="login-box">
                        <h2>Mon Restaurant</h2>
                        <form>
                            <div class="user-box">
                                <input type="text" name="" required="" onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value);}}/>
                                <label>Nom du restaurant</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-box">
                                <input type="text" name="" required="" onChange={(e) => { setAddress(e.target.value);}}/>
                                <label>Adresse du restaurant</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-box">
                                <input type="text" name="" required="" onChange={(e) => { setDescription(e.target.value);}}/>
                                <label>Description</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-box">
                                <input type="file" name="myFile" onChange={fileChangedHandler} />
                                <label>Importer une photo de votre établissement</label>
                            </div>                            
                            <a href="#" onClick={addMyRestaurantToDatabase}>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            Submit
                            </a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
    );

}


export default AjouterMonRestaurant;
```

So as you can see here, I tried with a FormData but I also tried with a normal (binary) sending but nothing is working. I have everytime this in my console VSCode :

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO restaurant VALUES ('zfzf','zfzf','zfzff',)"
}
```

but when I print with a `console.log(formData);` , everything is good. So I don't know why is my database don't receive the image.

PS : the *image_resto* column in the table *restaurant* is a VARBINARY(255) type.

Comment: While possible to do, I would advise against storing files inside databases for one main reason: it makes your database bigger in size. Instead, a common approach is to only save the relative path to the file in the database, and keep the actual file on your filesystem.

Comment: i cant do this because images are not my images, it is images that every users of my website can upload in a html form

Comment: Yes, so you can save the image that they upload to a folder inside your app. Save the relative path to where you saved it in your app in the database